# Unexpected token 'export' in lodash-es

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, lodash

I move from `lodash` to `lodash-es` in my typescript project .

I installed `lodash-es` and `@types/lodash-es`.

But when I compile using webpack my project it throw an error:

```
C:\..\node_modules\lodash-es\lodash.js:10
export { default as add } from './add.js';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1116:16)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:27)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
```

I'm not sure what the problem and how to solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your error, looks like you are trying to load a esm module in node (v14+), by default only latest node version supports this kind of files.

There is no reason to use `lodash-es` in node enviroment.

The benefit of using `lodash-es` comes in browser related code, which will be bundled with one of the bundlers & enables a tree-shaking optimization.

Comment: hello, what if I have some shared code from "frontend" which is served in browser (using angular) and my node backend is using some files from there that are using lodash-es? Is there some solution you think?

Comment: It depends, for example if you bundle your node code with webpack, it will just work.